# How do I change the default screenshot location on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I take screenshots on OSX a lot using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

Mac OS X automatically drops them on my Desktop, which is not my favorite place.  Is there some way to configure these shortcuts to save screenshots in another location?

Comment: If you take a lot of screenshots, you might want to check out the free app called InstantShot! http://projects.digitalwaters.net/index.php?q=instantshot I prefer it much more over the default screencap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found [Here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050824073301844&lsrc=osxh), the command is

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Full/Path/To/Folder`

Will take effect after a logout and login. ~ as the home folder doesn't work.

Comment: Considering ~ does not work for the home folder, is this not a per-user setting?

Comment: you can also type: killall SystemUIServer, to immediately bring it into effect without logout and login ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Throw a Ctrl key in the mix.  That copies the shot to the clipboard, then paste it into your favorite editor.

Ctrl+Shift+Cmd+3 copies the whole screen, or Ctrl+Shift+Cmd+4 lets you select what you want to copy and hitting the spacebar with the selection option active turns it into a camera, use this to get a shot of a window without having to crop it.